# Triggers mysql sql

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Whats wrong with this code?

```
CREATE TRIGGER User_trigger AFTER DELETE ON users
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO del_users ('fullname') VALUES ('fullname');
END;
```

Please help.

Comment: what is the issue you have, please add details the error may be somewhere else

Comment: also you dont need a semi-colon after END

Comment: Mysql error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''fullname') VALUES ('fullname')' at line 4

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. If you use `BEGIN ... END` block you have to change `DELIMITER`. On the other hand if your trigger contains only one statement just don't use `BEGIN ... END`. Take a closer look at [Defining Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html)
2. In MySQL to be able to refer to columns of a row being deleted you have to use `OLD` keyword. Take a closer look at [Trigger Syntax and Examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

That being said and assuming that your simplified table schema look something like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  fullname varchar(8)
);
CREATE TABLE del_users
(
  id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  user_id int, fullname varchar(32),
  deleted datetime
);
```

Your trigger would look

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_users 
AFTER DELETE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO del_users (user_id, fullname, deleted)
  VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.fullname, NOW());
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e9ac/1)** demo

or with `BEGIN ... END` block

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tg_ad_users 
AFTER DELETE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO del_users (user_id, fullname, deleted)
  VALUES (OLD.id, OLD.fullname, NOW());
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae94fa/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER User_trigger AFTER DELETE 
ON users
AS
    INSERT INTO del_users (fullname) 
    SELECT d.fullname from Deleted d
```

Here is information on using the DELETED and INSERTED Tables:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS INSERT INTO del_users (fullname) SELECT fullname from del_users' at line 3

Comment: Also i tryed
CREATE TRIGGER Usertrigger AFTER DELETE ON users
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO del_users (fullname, cpr, city, email, pw, ip, time, token, active, sid, avatar, sex, phone, about, last_udt_time) VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
END;

and it give me an error
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Comment: There is no `deleted` pseudo table in MySQL. It's for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes. I made the mistake of thinking that this was a MSSQL question and not a MySQL question.  I will update with a MySQL solution later if this has not been answered by then.  My apologies for my misunderstanding.